# How to keep the dock always visible when connecting on remote desktop (xrdp)

Tags: xrdp, dock

I 'v followed the steps from this URl https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13590, it helped me to configure my gnome when connecting remotely, specially to add the dock, currently is displaying the dock enlarged but it hides when maximizing any window:
[Before maximize a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFsO.png)
[After maximize a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKHqh.png)

I uncheck the "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide-in-fullscreen" option from the dconf-editor, and still dock is getting hide

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, on Ubuntu 22.04. It's possible this was a different underlying issue than asked in the question, but it looks similar from the outside.

1. Install Gnome Extensions Manager (may already be installed as `Extensions Manager`)
2. Use Gnome Extension Manager to browse for and install Dash-to-Dock (by micxgx)
3. It warned me that it was not supported yet, and that only Ubuntu Dock is supported.
4. I activated anyway - I am not sure how as it still says it is off (!). I think it was by turning Ubuntu Dock off and then on again, or by clicking the settings icon of the Dash to Dock.
5. I then used dconf editor (installed separately) to manage settings. There are several which may be important. For me the critical one was `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/autohide`. Intellihide and intellihide-mode are some other ones that might be issues. Settings reloaded to apply.

And viola! Dock is always visible from XRDP. There may be other approaches using Ubuntu Dock settings or other extensions that solve this.